# Everything EXCEPT in perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a bunch of formulas that I want to grab from a pdf file. The formulas are preceded by the formula description as follows:

```
Revenues (IQ_REV_UTI)
Other Revenues, Total (IQ_OTHER_REV_UTI)
Total Revenues (IQ_TOTAL_REV_UTI)
```

I just want to grab everything inside the brackets (i.e. IQ_REV_UTI ).

I can match everything I want using the following regex:  `IQ\w+`
However, the program I am using on my mac (called Patterns) doesnt let me extract the matched text. It only lets me find and replace. Therefore, I need to find a way to match everything except what I want to extract. I can then replace it with nothing and hopefully I will be left with what I am after (i.e. just the forumlas inside the brackets). Alternatively, are there any other regex programs that let me simply extract the matched text?

Comment: How are you using your regex? Could you show us some code?

Comment: Is your data formatted as the edit currently shows or how you originally posted it?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but you can use grep like this:

```
grep -Eo "IQ\w+" yourfile
IQ_REV_UTI
IQ_OTHER_REV_UTI
IQ_TOTAL_REV_UTI
```

In the light of your revised post, I sense you can only use search and replace within your application, and external scripts/tools do not help you. So, how about this:

```
search for ".*(" and replace with "nothing"
search for ").*" and replace with "nothing"
```

Depending on the patterns your application accepts, the search string may be

```
"*("
".*("
```

and

```
").*"
")*"
```

Comment: Updated... see new second part.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex like so:

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

my @file = ('Revenues (IQ_REV_UTI)', 'Other Revenues, Total (IQ_OTHER_REV_UTI)', 'Total Revenues (IQ_TOTAL_REV_UTI)', 'Line with no brackets...');

foreach (@file){
    my ($info) = /\((.+?)\)/;
    print "$info\n" if $info;
}
```

Prints:

```
IQ_REV_UTI
IQ_OTHER_REV_UTI
IQ_TOTAL_REV_UTI
```

Comment: See the question edit, the sample input was over multiple lines. Also, your regex captures the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

apologies but I am not programming. I use an app that allows you to use regex to find and replace text. I dont think I can use any of the programming functions suggested such as grep or anything else. I was just wondering if there was to way to match everyything except simply through the regular expression alone.